# Delete a table and combobox in the table using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm new to vba programming in excel and I have written a macro which basically creates a table with combobx in the second column this is the sample macro I wrote (not the exact macro):

```
Sub Proc1()
    Cells(2, 1).Value = "MAT10"
    Cells(2, 2).Value = "Material ID (MID)"
    Cells(2, 3).Value = "Bulk Modulus(B)"
    Cells(2, 4).Value = "Average Density (rho)"
    Cells(2, 5).Value = "Speed of sound (C)"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$2:$E$2"), , xlYes).name = "Tab2"
        'No go in 2003
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab2").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
    With Range("B3:B3")
    Set Comb = ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)

    End With
    With Comb
     .AddItem "75000000"
     .AddItem "75000001"
     .AddItem "75000002"
     .AddItem "75000003"
     .AddItem "75000004"
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I want to write a macro even to delete the table if necessary which I have written but the problem is I cannot delete the combobox please can any one help me with this

macro for deleting which I wrote is:

```
Sub delprop()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab2").Delete

End Sub
```

Now I want to delete the combobox as well how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need small modification in your delprop subroutine. Check this code:

```
Sub delprop()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tab2").Delete

''To delete all dropdowns on activesheet.
ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Delete

End Sub
```